# Oracle XE query log

Tags: oracle, logging

In Postgres you can switch on query logging, resulting in a file containing all queries issued by any client.

Is there a similar possibility in Oracle XE? How do I switch it on and where do I find the resulting file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would:

alter session set sql_trace=true;

The trace file will be in the udump subdirectory under the installation directory.

Edit: Actually the docs say that `sql_trace` is deprecated in 10g: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams205.htm#REFRN10208

It looks like `DBMS_SESSION` is the way to go now:

eg.

```
EXECUTE DBMS_SESSION.SESSION_TRACE_ENABLE(waits => TRUE, binds => FALSE);
```

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/sqltrace.htm#CHDDGCCB

Comment: Seems to me that this is what I search. But when I execute the query, I get an 0RA-00900 error (invalid query).

Comment: When you execute "DBMS_SESSION.SESSION_TRACE_ENABLE(waits => TRUE, binds => FALSE); "?

Comment: How are you executing it, and from what environment? In PL/SQL you would omit the EXECUTE, which is generally used in client tools as a shortcut for wrapping a PL/SQL command in BEGIN ... END;

Comment: @Nap `SELECT VALUE FROM V$PARAMETER WHERE NAME = 'user_dump_dest'`

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting a specific application, you might find useful to use [p6spy](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy) which is *"an open source framework that intercept and optionally modify database statements"*

Can be used with JBoss, ATG, Orion, JOnAS, iPlanet, WebLogic, WebSphere, Resin and Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

If you log into the web admin interface, and go into administration, you'll "Top-SQL" .... It has a search functionality, you can supply part of the query your looking for.  I find that to be very helpful.