# Oracle SQL Query logging

Tags: sql, oracle, logging

I'm using Oracle 11g Standard Edition.

I would like to log all SQL queries, that are being executed by users, into a table.

How can this be done?

Comment: For what purpose do you want this information?  Is it auditing?  Usage monitoring?  Something else?

Comment: It's for auditing (select, update, insert, delete)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570978/oracle-xe-query-log

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're using a modern version of the database (9i or later) and you have an Enterprise Edition license you can use Fine-Graining Auditing.  It allows us to audit user queries at a very low level of granularity, through defined policies.

To capture SQL text and bind variables you will need to set the AUDIT_TRAIL parameter appropriately when adding an FGA Policy.  [Find out more](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/cfgaudit.htm#i1011302).

---

> "i'm using an 11g standard, so auditing functions are not supported."

Not exactly.  The AUDIT command is part of the standard Oracle build, but it only allows us to capture when a given user issues a SELECT against a given table.  But, yes, to find out exactly *what* they are selecting requires Enterprise Edition license.

Also there is no ON SELECT trigger, so we cannot roll our own.

---

> "So can i use AUDIT command in the standard edition? ... But then a
>   consultant told me, that i cannot use it without paying enterprise
>   license? "

Speaking as a consultant myself, I do have to say those guys don't always know what they are talking about.

So let's be clear:

- the AUDIT command is part of Oracle SQL.  It is usable with the Standard Edition.  In fact since 11g it is enabled by default.  It audits general activity.  [Find out more](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e16543/auditing.htm#BCGCJFEG).
- Fine Grained Auditing is a PL/SQL package with is only usable if you have the Enterprise Edition.  It allows us to audit user activity at a very low level. [Find out more](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e16543/auditing.htm#CEGBAFIA).

Comment: i'm using an 11g standard, so auditing functions are not supported. :/

Comment: So can i use AUDIT command in the standard edition? I already had it working for 2 tables. But then a consultant told me, that i cannot use it without paying enterprise license?

Answer (score 0):

For QUICK, EASY logging of SQL, [try my monitoring answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36896729/3175487). Not for long-term logging, but works great just to see what is going on in a small time window. :-)