# oracle jdbc statement tracer

Tags: java, oracle, gwt, jdbc, monitoring

I looking for a software to trace all the statements on my oracle database.
I have a Delphi application (without the source code) and there are many stored procedures called. To trace all the query executed I'm using this tool:
[Statement Tracer for Oracle](http://www.aboves.com/products/statement_tracer_for_oracle/ss1.html)

It works great.
Now, I have a web application (Java + GWT using JDBC to connect to the DB) and I need to do the same thing. I don't want only the calls from my app to the db but every statement executed inside stored procedure.
Does anybody know a tool in able to do that ?

Comment: yourkit has an sql api too

Comment: An option may be enabling the server audit tools. See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914354/oracle-sql-query-logging

Answer (score 0):

There's a jdbc tracer project https://github.com/tokuhirom/jdbc-tracer  where you can import the project through maven and implement some listeners, receiving the SQL statements and other info from the JDBC Statements. I'm sure that if you create a visual project through its maven library you can create a sorta visual interface showing all SQL Queries done through a JDBC driver.