# How to find which SQL Executed on a date in Oracle 9i

Tags: sql, oracle, logging, oracle9i

I would like to get Logs or SQL executed on a perticular Date. I tried with v$sql and v$sqlarea. But its not giving old logs. Please help. I need to investigate a big mistake happened  on last month.

Comment: From a month ago, this will only work if you have Oracle Enterprise  with fine grained auditing turned on; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830875/find-out-the-history-of-sql-queries and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914354/oracle-sql-query-logging. Do you?

Answer (score 0):

The only option I see is to restore an old backup to an auxiliary database and try to find the exact time when the mistake happened.

Afterwards you can compare the current database with the auxiliary database and restore the data manually with export or database link + standard sql.

It depends on what went wrong this will be pretty difficult. In any case I wish you good luck!!